# Decrypting zip file encrypted by gpg

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

When i am trying to decrypt this file in shell using cmd below:

```
gpg test.zip.asc
```

After giving the pass I am getting decrypted file `"test.zip"` in same folder but using python script I am not able to get the decrypted file. No error occurs, any idea on what I'm doing wrong ?

```
import gnupg

def testgpg():    
    print "testgpg function started"

    encrypted_file = "test.zip.asc"
    passwd = "passwd"
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/home/centos/.gnupg')
    try:
        print "trying"
        gpg.decrypt(encrypted_file, passphrase=passwd)
        print "decrypted"
    except Exception as e:
        print "not decrypted: -->", str(e)

testgpg()
```

Comment: What do you mean you "are not able to get"? Does `gpg.decrypt()` return anything? If so, I would suspect this would be the decrypted file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs for gnupg](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#decryption):

> To decrypt a message, use the following approach:
>   `>>> decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt(data)`

The module doesn't decrypt the file and save it in the same directory as the original file like the gpg binary. Instead it returns a string of the decrypted data.

However, you also have another problem. `gpg.decrypt()` is trying to decrypt the value stored in `encrpyted_file`, which of course is just the string `"test.zip.asc"`. Instead, you want to decrypt the contents of the file with that name. For that, you need to use `gpg.decrypt_file()` like so:

```
# Open the encrypted file (gpg will handle reading it)
with open(encrypted_file, 'rb') as src:
    # decrypt the file and store its decrypted contents
    decrypted_contents = gpg.decrypt_file(src, passphrase=passwd)
    # write the decrypted contents to a new file
    with open('destination_file.zip', 'wb') as dst:
        dst.write(decrypted_contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

The decrypt_file method allows to provide a path to a output file like so:

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=config.gnupgHome)
with open(encryptedZippedApp, 'rb') as src:
    status = gpg.decrypt_file(src, output='/tmp/myout.zip')

print('ok: ', status.ok)
```